# What is the meaning of qr// in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am completely new to perl and trying to design a lexer where I have come across:

```
my @token_def =
 (
        [Whitespace => qr{\s+},     1],
        [Comment    => qr{#.*\n?$}m,   1],
  );
```

and even after going through multiple sites I did not understand the meaning.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qr.html

Comment: "man perlop" or [**Regexp Quote-Like Operators** in "perlop"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)

Answer (score 21):

`qr//` is one of the quote-like operators that apply to pattern matching and related activities.

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators):

> This operator quotes (and possibly compiles) its STRING as a regular expression. STRING is interpolated the same way as PATTERN in m/PATTERN/. If `'` is used as the delimiter, no interpolation is done.

From [modern_perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/chapter_06.html):

> The qr// operator creates first-class regexes. Interpolate them into the match operator to use them:

```
my $hat = qr/hat/;
say 'Found a hat!' if $name =~ /$hat/;
```

... or combine multiple regex objects into complex patterns:

```
my $hat   = qr/hat/;
my $field = qr/field/;

say 'Found a hat in a field!'
if $name =~ /$hat$field/;

like( $name, qr/$hat$field/,
            'Found a hat in a field!' );
```

Comment: How is this different from `m/`?

Comment: @Lou - `qr` effectively compiles the regular expression before it is run, whereas `m` 'compiles' it on the fly.

Comment: maybe needless to say, but to use the `like` function you need to load the `test::more` module, as `like` is not part of the core perl functions

Answer (score 5):

`qr//` is documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) in the "Regexp Quote-Like Operators" section.

Just like `qq"..."` aka `"..."` allows you to construct a string, `qr/.../` allows you to construct a regular expression.

```
$s = "abc";     # Creates a string and assigns it to $s
$s = qq"abc";   # Same as above. 
print("$s\n");

$re = qr/abc/;   # Creates a compiled regex pattern and assigns it to $x
print "match\n" if $s =~ /$re/;
```

The quoting rules for `qr/.../` are very similar to `qq"..."`'s. The only difference is that `\` followed by a non-word character are passed through unchanged.

Comment: After using `$re = qr/abc/`, it seems like you can just do `$s =~ $re` without the forward-slashes, since the forward-slashes are effectively compiling the regex and you have have already done that with `qr`.

Comment: @CJ7 yup, just like you can do `$s =~ "abc"`. In the absence of a qr//, m//, s/// or tr/// operator, a match operator (m//) is implied by the binding operator. But no, `/$re/` doesn't recompile the regex.