# POSIX (isprint) has been deleted; what to do?

Tags: perl, posix

A Perl modules uses

```
use POSIX qw(isprint);
```

Which has been removed from Perl's POSIX.

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/POSIX) states:

> `isprint`
>
> This function has been removed as of v5.24. It was very similar to matching against `qr/ ^ [[:print:]]+ $ /x`, **which you should convert to use instead**. (...)

(emphasis: me)

So I guess this very likely answers your question.

Comment: Yes, of course that answered the question, but it didn't actually tell me anything that my skill set can make useful. 

So far, the only time I have found a reference to is:
`if (defined($str) && $str ne '' && !isprint($str)) {`
I am still combing through all the modules in the package.

Am I wanting to change:
`if (defined($str) && $str ne '' && !isprint($str)) {` to `if (defined($str) && $str ne '' && !qr/ ^ [[:print:]]+ $ /x) {` ?

Comment: @Harry_: `$_` might not be set to `$str` in your context, so probably an explicit match on it is safer: `... && $str !~ qr/ ^ [[:print:]]+ $ /x ...` or skip the `qr`, it doesn't seem useful to me there (but maybe that's just me): `$str !~ m/ ^ [[:print:]]+ $ /x`.

Comment: `if (defined($str) && $str ne '' && $str ne qr/ ^ [[:print:]]+ $ /x) {` seemed to do the trick. Also commenting out the `use POSIX qw(isprint);`

Thank you!

Comment: @Harry_ `$str ne qr/ ^ [[:print:]]+ $ /x` does not do what you intend. Reread sticky bit's comment if you don't know how to match a particular variable against a regular expression.

Comment: @Harry_ The qr operator just creates a regex reference. You need the [m operator](https://perldoc.pl/functions/m) to test if a string matches it.

Comment: Re "*it didn't actually tell me anything that my skill set can make useful.*", Then maybe you should have asked how to match against a regex pattern? Or googled for the answer? Even googling for just `perl qr` gives [this pertinent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093272/what-is-the-meaning-of-qr-in-perl) as the second search result.